# How to ensure runtime type covariance in C++?

Tags: c++, covariance

Say I have an interface class and templated subclass

```
struct IPort {
    virtual bool can_connect_to(std::shared_ptr<IPort> p) = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<IPort> receiver;
};

template <class T>
struct Port : IPort {
    bool can_connect_to(std::shared_ptr<IPort> p) override {
        // what goes here?
    }

    void send(T* t) {
        auto p = std::static_pointer_cast<Port>(receiver);
        p->on_recv(t);
    }

    std::function<void(T*)> on_recv;
};
```

The template parameter can be any type. I have some base types (`Base` and `Other` below) as well as a derived type (`Derived`).

```
struct Base {
    virtual const char* get_data() = 0;
    virtual size_t get_size() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    std::string str;
    const char* get_data() override { return str.c_str(); }
    size_t get_size() override { return str.size(); }
};

struct Other {
    double x, y, z;
};
```

Ideally I should be able to send a derived type from a port to another port that accepts the base type (e.g. `Port<Derived>` should be able to connect to `Port<Base>`). On the other hand, I should not be able to send incompatible types (`Port<Other>` should not be able to connect to `Port<Base>`).

```
auto sender1 = std::make_shared<Port<Derived>>();
auto sender2 = std::make_shared<Port<Other>>();
auto receiver = std::make_shared<Port<Base>>([](Base* t) {
    // do something with t
});

sender1->can_connect_to(receiver); // should return true
sender2->can_connect_to(receiver); // should return false
```

What can I put in `can_connect_to` to verify that the port passed in has a templated type that is a superclass of the template of the sending port?

Also, why does the `static_pointer_cast` in `send` work? It seems to do the correct thing, but I don't understand how it's even valid c++ since there's no template parameter to `Port`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to test whether an object "Is A" certain class or not at runtime is `dynamic_cast`.  So I think you need:

```
template <class T>
bool Port<T>::can_connect_to(std::shared_ptr<IPort> p) {
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(p.get());
}
```

This will also return false if `p` is a null pointer, which is probably what you want.

> Also, why does the `static_pointer_cast` in `send` work? It seems to do the correct thing, but I don't understand how it's even valid c++ since there's no template parameter to `Port`.

Inside a definition of a class template, or a definition of any of its members (or members of its nested class members, etc.), the name of the template can be used as an alias for the class type which uses that definition's template parameters.  That is, since that use of `Port` appears inside the definition `template <class T> struct Port {` ... `};`, the name `Port` with no template argument list means the same as `Port<T>`.  This is called the "injected class name".

Comment: +1 for "injected class name". However, in `can_connect_to`, I want to verify that `p` is a `Port` not just an `IPort` and that it's template parameter is a superclass of `T`.

Comment: Oh, oops. You're right, `p` will point to a `Port<T>`, not a `T`. I'll need to think about that some more.

Comment: I'm thinking this is essentially a double dispatch problem. There are some solutions out there for that class of problem, but none very simple.